# How can I add class attribute in formset field where we are using inlineformset_factory function

Tags: django, django-forms

If I add a unit_price field in SupplierForm it does reflect on my template and added class attribute but it added both forms. I want to override unit_price only entries form.how can I do that.

```
class SupplierForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # unit_price = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    #         attrs={
    #         'class':'product_price',
    #         }
    #     ))

    # VAT = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.TextInput(
    #         attrs={
    #         'class':'product_vat',
    #         }
    #     ))

    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        exclude = ['uploaded_by', 'approved_by','unit_price']
        labels = {
        "payment_due_date": "Payment Due Date / Paid Date"
         }
        help_texts = {
            'invoice_date': '<b>Click on arrow for calendar</b>',
            'payment_due_date': '<b>Click on arrow for calendar</b>',
        }
        widgets = {
            'invoice_date': DateInput(format="%d %b %Y"),
            'payment_due_date':DateInput(),

        }

# I have added here unit_price field for add class attribute in this field but there is no reflect on template
class EnteriesForm(ModelForm):
    unit_price = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
            'class':'product_price',
            }
        ))
    class Meta:
        model = Enteries
        exclude = ()
        help_texts = {
            'unit_price': '<b>Click on arrow for calendar</b>',

        }

EnteriesFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Supplier, Enteries,
                                            form=SupplierForm,exclude=['uploaded_by'],extra=1)
```

Comment: Your `EnteriesFormSet` is using `SupplierForm`, not `EntriesForm`, so any changes made to `EntriesForm` will not show up

Comment: Hi, #Carl Brubaker thanks for the kind reply, can you tell how can make that which I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can find it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-form), but you just change your `form`. And once you declare a `form`, you no longer need to use `fields` or `exclude` when declaring the `formset`, because all of that should be set in your `form`

```py
class EnteriesForm(ModelForm):
    unit_price = forms.FloatField(widget=forms.TextInput(
            attrs={
            'class':'product_price',
            }
        ))
    class Meta:
        model = Enteries
        exclude = ()
        help_texts = {
            'unit_price': '<b>Click on arrow for calendar</b>',
        }


EnteriesFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    Supplier,
    Enteries,
    # this is where you select what form you want to use:
    form=EntriesForm,
    # 'uploaded_by' is not even apart of this form.
    # You should remove this.
    # exclude=['uploaded_by'],
    # 'extra': default is '1', so you don't really need this.
    # extra=1
)
```

You really should go back and read all of the information on `formsets`. The inheritance is `formset` -> `modelformset` -> `inlineformset`, so everything that applies to `formset` applies to `inlineformset`.

Comment: Hi, #Carl Brubaker thanku so much for this solution, It's working fine. Thanks a lot for kind help.